# How to minimize $||\vec{y} - k (X \cdot \vec{w})||_2$

Tags: optimization, numerical-optimization

I am trying to find the $k, \vec{w}$ which are **argmin** of the following functionality:

$||\vec{y} - k (X \cdot \vec{w})||_2$ such that $\vec{1}^T \cdot \vec{w} = 1$, where $k$ is just a scalar value

I have obviously tried Lagrange multipliers - but the resulting system of equations is not linear & I did not manage to find the unique solution.

**Questions:**

- What is the best way to **prove** that the problem is **convex** (or potentially not convex)?
- Is there **another way** to find the theoretical solution
- Is **numerical** optimization the only way to go here?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: $X$ and $y$ are constant?  What do you mean by $\|\cdot\|_2$?  Isn't $y - k (X \cdot \vec{w})$ a scalar?

Comment: @saulspatz That is right $(y, X)$ are given & constant. $X$ is a matrix - so $X \cdot \vec{w}$ is a vector. So $\vec{y} - k (X \cdot \vec{w})$ is a vector as well. The task is to minimize $L_2$-norm of the resulting difference vector over parameters $k, \vec{w}$

Comment: You should make all this clear in the question.

Comment: @saulspatz I thought it was pretty clear from the notations... But appreciate the correction! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can equivalently consider $\min_{\beta} \|y - X \beta\|_2$ with the constraint $1^\top \beta \ne 0$. (If we find a minimizer $\tilde{\beta}$, then we can take $k = 1^\top \tilde{\beta}$ and $w = \tilde{\beta} / (1^\top \tilde{\beta})$.) The constraint set is not a closed convex set, which leads to some issues.

---

Consider the unconstrained problem $\min_\beta \|y - X \beta\|_2$ (no constraints on $\beta$).

Suppose there exists a minimizer $\hat{\beta}$ to the unconstrained problem such that $\vec{1}^\top \hat{\beta} \ne 0$. Then this will also be a minimizer of the constrained problem, and we are done.

However, a problem arises if all minimizers $\hat{\beta}$ of the unconstrained problem satisfy $\vec{1}^\top \hat{\beta} = 0$. Excluding the uninteresting case where $X$ is the zero matrix, we will have a situation where minimizing  the constrained problem will drive us to choose $\tilde{\beta}$ close to a solution $\hat{\beta}$ to the unconstrained problem. But we can choose $\tilde{\beta}$ arbitrarily close to $\hat{\beta}$ and drive $\|y - X \tilde{\beta}\|_2$ smaller and smaller approaching $\|y - X \hat{\beta}\|_2$ but we can never reach it while staying within the constraint $\vec{1}^\top \tilde{\beta} \ne 0$.

Comment: That is a great way to think about the issue! Thank you for your answer! You are right - it seems that the task is not correctly defined... However, in practice - I imagine that the case when $1^T \hat{\beta} $ is exactly $0$ should not appear too much - so we can just probably go with the first scenario..